# Does there exists a finite index non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

let $\mathbb{C}^*$ be a multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers.

Suppose that $H$ be a subgroup of finite index of $\mathbb{C}^*$.Prove that $H=\mathbb{C}^*$

Attempt

If $[\mathbb{C}^*.H]=n$ then if $xH \in \frac{\mathbb{C}^*}{H}$ then $\left(xH\right)^n=H$ implies $x^n \in H$.

Because $x$ is random we have $\left(\mathbb{C}^*\right)^n=\mathbb{C}^* \in H$

Note that $\left(\mathbb{C}^*\right)^n=\mathbb{C}^*$

Comment: For your solution: why is $\left(\mathbb{C}^*\right)^n=\mathbb{C}^*$?

Comment: I think you mean “$x$ is arbitrary” instead of “$x$ is random.”  It would be sufficient to show $1 \in H$.